# Solr variable from parent entity not set in child entity

Tags: solr, parent-child, block

I'm facing a very weird problem. Here is my case. My documents is composed of 2 entities, each one from different databases. Below is part of my bd-data-config.xml (some code has been modified/stripped for security purpose)

```html
<document>
  <entity name="process_oracle" datasource="oracle" query="
    select 'oracle-' || p.process_id as id, p.process_id from tb_process p">
    <field column="process_id" name="process_id"/>
    
    <entity name="subject" datasource="oracle" query="
      select distinct sub.subject
      from tb_subject sub, tb_process_subject prc_sub
      where sub.id_subject = prc_sub.id_subject
        and prc_sub.id_process = ${process_oracle.process_id}">
      <field column="subject" name="subject"/>
    </entity>
  </entity>

  <entity name="process_postgresql" datasource="postgresql" query="
    select 'postgresql-' || p.process_id as id, p.process_id from tb_process p">
    <field column="process_id" name="process_id"/>
    
    <entity name="subject" datasource="postgresql" query="
      select distinct sub.subject
      from tb_subject sub, tb_process_subject prc_sub
      where sub.id_subject = prc_sub.id_subject
        and prc_sub.id_process = ${process_postgresql.process_id}">
      <field column="subject" name="subject"/>
    </entity>
  </entity>
</document>
```

When I execute the import, it runs normally. No error is reported at Web Admin interface nor at log, althought, here is the weird thing. Whilst the subjects of process_postgresql are indexed, the subjects of process_oracle are not. Here a small piece of the output query.

```js
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1583958908786"}},
  "response":{"numFound":7,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "process_id":"oracle-1"
      },
...
      {
        "process_id":"postgresql-12",
        "subject":["subject1", "subject2"]
      }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the subjects from postgresql are indexed, meanwhile those from oracle are not.
When I checked the log (run in debug mode) I noticed this:

```
2020-03-13 11:52:47.085 DEBUG (Thread-33) [   ] o.a.s.h.d.JdbcDataSource Executing SQL:      select distinct sub.subject from tb_subject sub, tb_process_subject prc_sub where sub.id_subject = prc_sub.id_subject and prc_sub.id_process = 
...
2020-03-13 11:52:47.953 DEBUG (Thread-33) [   ] o.a.s.h.d.JdbcDataSource Executing SQL:      select distinct sub.subject from tb_subject sub, tb_process_subject prc_sub  where sub.id_subject = prc_sub.id_subject and prc_sub.id_process = 12
```

As you can see, the problem is that the variable ${process_oracle.process_id} is not been set, meanwhile the variable ${process_postgresql.process_id} runs just fine.

Does anyone have a clue of why is it happening?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days, I could solve the problem. The variable must be in upper case. So It must look like that:

```html
<document>
  <entity name="process_oracle" datasource="oracle" query="
    select 'oracle-' || p.process_id as id, p.process_id from tb_process p">
    <field column="process_id" name="process_id"/>
    
    <entity name="subject" datasource="oracle" query="
      select distinct sub.subject
      from tb_subject sub, tb_process_subject prc_sub
      where sub.id_subject = prc_sub.id_subject
        and prc_sub.id_process = ${process_oracle.PROCESS_ID}">
      <field column="subject" name="subject"/>
    </entity>
  </entity>

  <entity name="process_postgresql" datasource="postgresql" query="
    select 'postgresql-' || p.process_id as id, p.process_id from tb_process p">
    <field column="process_id" name="process_id"/>
    
    <entity name="subject" datasource="postgresql" query="
      select distinct sub.subject
      from tb_subject sub, tb_process_subject prc_sub
      where sub.id_subject = prc_sub.id_subject
        and prc_sub.id_process = ${process_postgresql.PROCESS_ID}">
      <field column="subject" name="subject"/>
    </entity>
  </entity>
</document>
```

That's it. As simple as that.